# third ajax dropdown returns wrong results

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have 3 dropdown list (semester,section and subject) if I choose  a semester it will populate section.
Now if I choose a section it will populate subject but it does not read semester. it just display all the available subjects of the chosen section not considering what semester it is.

```
function showSEMESTER(semester) 
{
    var item = semester;
    var dataString = 'semester='+ semester;
    $.ajax
    ({
        type: "POST",
        url: "class-select.php",
        data: dataString,
        cache: false,
        success: function(html)
    {
        $("#class_id").html(html);
    } 
    });
}
function showSubject(section) 
    {
        var item = section;
        var dataString = 'code='+ item;
        $.ajax
        ({
            type: "POST",
            url: "subject-select.php",
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,
            success: function(html)
        {
            $("#subject_id").html(html);
        } 
        });
    }
```

here is the sql for subject select

```
    $query = "select * from subject where class_id = '$_POST[code]' and semester_id='$_POST[semester]' ";
```

this does not return any $_post[semester]

Comment: I'm interested in taking a class on `'; DROP TABLE subject; --`. Can you tell me when the next classes are, please?

Answer (score 1):

change

```
$query = "select * from subject where class_id = '$_POST[code]' and semester_id='$_POST[semester]' ";
```

to

```
$query = 'select * from subject where class_id = "'.$_POST['code'].'" and semester_id="'.$_POST['semester'].'"';
```

$_POST is an array with string indexes. You lack quotes `""` or `''` for the $_POST indexes.